# Is it possible extend PayPal subscriptions as a gift?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

Is there a way we can extend one customer's subscription duration as a gift? Let's say I have a subscription plan which has 1 billing cycle repeated infinite times. During a promotional event I would like to gift certain users an additional 30 days of subscription period. Their subscription should continue normally from the next billing cycle once the 30 day period is over. In their [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions_patch) to update an existing subscription, the patch object doesn't allow to change the `billing_cycle` or any other field related to it.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether it's best, but the possibility that  occurs to me is [suspension](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#suspend-subscription) and reactivation 30 days later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Does the suspension consumes the subscription cycle ? In other words will subscribed duration remains the same before and after the suspension ?

Comment: I think you'll want to try creating and suspending some profiles in sandbox, and later re-activating them, to determine the exact behavior.